# To find analytic function with given condition

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find  all analytic function on the disc $\{z:|z-1|<1 \}$ with $f(1)=1$ and $f(z)=f(z^2)$ ?.

Comment: Kind of a strange problem because the function $z^2$ does not preserve $\{|z-1|<1\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the domain $\left\{ | z| < 1\right\}$ is included in the domain of convergence of the logarithm, you can write $w = \log z$ and $g(w) = f(z) = f(\exp w)$. Your conditions then becomes $g(2w) = g(w)$. For $g$ continuous at zero, this is enough to show that $g$ is constant (because, for any $w$, $f(w) = f(w/2) = f(w/4) = \dots$, and this sequence has $f(0)$ as a limit because of continuity).

Answer (score 2):

For any $z = re^{i\theta}, r \gt 0$ in the disc, the sequence $z_n = r^{1 \over 2^n} e^{i \theta /2^n}$ will converge to $1$, and $f(z_n) = f(z_n^{2^n}) = f(z)$.  Since $f$ is continuous, $f(z) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(z_n) = f(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z_n) = f(1) = 1$

Comment: ok then function will be constant function i.e. 1??

Comment: @YOGESH Yes. Zeros of analytic functions are isolated. What about $f(z)-1$ ?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot..